# Android HighChart (SyntaxError : ParseError)

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview, highcharts

I new to html and highchart and I wanted to ask what causes this error? I'm developing this for android and I got stucked here. Any comments and answers will be appreciated.

```
03-25 08:15:49.827: E/Web Console(692): SyntaxError: Parse error at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:35
```

Below is my html file

**html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js" type="text/javascript">   </script>
<title>My HTML</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(function () { 
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'bar'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Fruit Consumption'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Fruit eaten'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Jane',
            data: [1, 0, 4]
        }, {
            name: 'John',
            data: [5, 7, 3]
        }]
    });
});​  <---------------Line 35
</script>   
<div id="container" style="height: 300px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Activity**

```
    webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();  
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webSettings.setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
```

Comment: This problem appears in each browsers or only in android device? Which version of android do you use and which browser (webkit ? )

Comment: I run it on android 2.3.5 and also android 3.0 (emulator). Both also encounter error. Actually I initialize highchart in my webview.

Comment: If you copied code from jsFiddle, try to remove last line (with that comment '<---- Line 35') and write on your own.

Comment: I tried that, still not working